# Is there a test that can give a significant result for a 2x2 table with all the counts in one cell?

Tags: contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test

`fisher.test()` in `R` does not give a significant p-value for the first 2x2 table below. But the fact that all counts concentrate in one cell suggests something is unusual. It is just that the assumption used in `fisher.test()` may not be appropriate for cases like this.

For example, consider a hidden process which can generate a series of objects $o_i$, and each object can generate two random numbers $X$ and $Y$, where $X \in \{0, 1\}$ and $Y \in \{0, 1\}$. Now, lets consider two scenarios.

1. All the observed values of $X$ $x_i$'s are $1$'s and all the observed values of $Y$ $y_i$'s are $1$'s.
2. All the observed values of $X$ $x_i$'s are $1$'s, but some observed values of $Y$ $y_i$'s are $1$'s and the rest are $0$'s.

It is "intuitive" that the $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s are more similar in scenario 1 than in scenario 2. However, the following two `fisher.test()`s give the same results.

Does anybody know an alternative test which still give a significant result for the first 2x2 table?

```
R> fisher.test(rbind(c(0,0), c(0, 10)), alternative='greater')

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  rbind(c(0, 0), c(0, 10))
p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is greater than 1
95 percent confidence interval:
   0 Inf
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
         0 
R> fisher.test(rbind(c(0,0), c(5, 5)), alternative='greater')

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  rbind(c(0, 0), c(5, 5))
p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is greater than 1
95 percent confidence interval:
   0 Inf
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
         0
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "unusual."  When all counts are in one cell that implies the marginal distributions are concentrated in the corresponding row and column, that's all.  As @gammer asks, what is the hypothesis you're trying to test?

Comment: I think the inter-ocular trauma test is appropriate here (the effect hits you between the eyes).

Comment: @David Could you indicate what the effect is that you find so obvious?  After all, Fisher's Test finds no evidence of any kind against its particular null hypothesis.

Comment: @whuber see my added explanation in the question on why it should be "significant".

Comment: @whuber. I wasn't clear but was  thinking that even though the Fisher Exact assumes fixed marginals, it doesn't seem likely the experiment was designed to have those marginals. Since one row has no observations then nothing about contingency can be said (as shown by the confidence interval), but if sampling were random, it can be said that the proportion in column 2 is greater than in column 1.

Answer (score 2):

Contingency table tests like Fisher's test are designed to test for independence between the rows and columns. No such statistical test will ever give a significant result for a $2\times 2$ table when all the counts are in a single diagonal cell. The reason for this is that such a count table is fully compatible with independence.

Let's consider your latent variables $X$ and $Y$. In your first scenario, it appears from the count data that $X=1$ with probability one and that $Y=1$ with probability one. And it is a general result in probability theory that any random variable that takes a single value with probability 1 must be independent of all other random variables. This makes perfect sense from an intuitive point of view: a random variable that always takes the same value must be unaffected by other variables and hence must be independent of them.

Of course, if you had a table with one non-zero count in an off-diagonal position, then the opposite would be true. In that case, all contingency table tests including Fisher's will give a significant result if the count is sufficiently large.

Comment: ... but of course such a test with all counts in one cell will give a test with zero power!

Comment: ... which is a problem with the experimental design leading to the data collection rather than problem with the test method.